# Python input возможен без паузы?

Tags: python, input

Задумка чтобы после вопроса шёл отсчёт времени и можно было ответить на вопрос. Но как сделать ввод, чтобы не останавливался счётчик времени ?

```
import time
print('кто хочет стать мидионером ?')

start=time.clock()
t=time.clock()-start
while t<=10:
    t=time.clock()-start
    print(t)
    a=input()
    if a=="":continue
    else:break
```

Comment: Запускать ввод и счётчик в отдельных потоках

Comment: Там самое интересное будет основной цикл прерывать из потока. Рекомендую наоборот : input перекинуть в тред

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input() - блокирует всё и дожидается ответа с консоли, можно просто поставить таймер в отдельный поток и проверять там

```
from threading import Thread
import time, os

answer = None
timeout = 10

def check():
    for i in range(timeout):
        print(i+1)
        time.sleep(1)

        if answer != None:
            return

    print("Никто")
    os.abort()

print("Кто хочет стать миллионером?")
Thread(target = check).start()

answer = input()
```

Comment: Точно не надо внутри потока объявить global answer?